# Smooth streaming from azure cdn

Tags: azure, streaming, cdn

I have smooth streaming working on my local machine. The video plays nicely and it's working as expected but when I copy the same files to azure blob storage and to azure cdn, it does not work. I have setup azure websites with azure sql, azure  blob storage and azure cdn. Everything works except the streaming. I'm able to access pictures and other stuff from cdn. When I type the mediaURL with .ism/Manifest, I do not get any xml (but I do get a download prompt without /Manifetst). What am I missing? Should I enable smooth streaming somewhere in the cdn? PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused due to the fact that you didn't change the content type to **text/xml** (this is probably why you're getting a download prompt).

Instead of trying to manage all of this yourself I suggest you take a look at the Adaptive Streaming with [Windows Azure Blobs Uploader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/streamingazure) project, which has some nice features:

> - Upload video content to Windows Azure via a command-line tool (AdaptiveStreamingAzure.exe)
> - Upload video content from within Expression Encoder 3 via a publisher plugin.
> - Easily publish Smooth Streaming content produced with Expression Encoder, including player templates.
> - Automatically enable cross-domain access for easy embedding of videos.
> - Resume aborted uploads.
> - Integrate with CDNs (including the Windows Azure CDN) and control their cache policies.
> - Parallelize storage operations to decrease upload time.
> - Automatically check for new versions of the software.

Read more about this on Steve's blog: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/smooth-streaming-with-windows-azure-blobs-and-cdn

Besides that I suggest you also take a look at the new **Media Services** which has been launched as preview just recently: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/media-services (there is a sample to deliver streaming content)

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandrino, Thanks for the reply. I changed the content type of .ism to text/xml. I still do not see the video nor do I see the xml when type the url with /Manifest. I'm using cloudberry azure blob explorer tool (which works more like any ftp tool) to upload the files to azure blob storage. Anything i'm missing? Here is the link to .ism file: http://az280594.vo.msecnd.net/athadu/athadu480.ism/Manifest. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply use the URL without the /Manifest part? This works for me: http://az280594.vo.msecnd.net/athadu/athadu480.ism

Comment: tried that, I still don't see the video which I was able to see from my local machine. http://itheateralpha.azurewebsites.net/movies/stream

Answer (score 2):

Smooth Streaming via the Windows Azure CDN is still in preview, and you need to sign up to join that preview.

As Sandrino mentioned, I wrote a tool that pre-chunks the video so it can be served without any special streaming functionality in the CDN. That does work, but you'd have to actually run my tool. It does *not* just copy the files into blob storage.